# Whether rejecting suggested edits voted down your reputation?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have rejected suggested edits by someone on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341775/get-count-of-continuous-dates-in-mysql). Reviewer has added [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag on my question. I have only one tag [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) on my question. I have rejected the suggestion of adding **SQL** tag because SQL works on database Oracle. There are sometimes, complex situations, or queries which can be handled by SQL, but not by MySQL. So, I rejected the addition of tag. If SQL tag is added, then some reviewers, or users may give answers in SQL which I don't need. I just need solutions purely in MySQL only. Then, why my reputation is lost by 2 by Stack Overflow? Whether I have done anything wrong by rejecting the suggested edit, even if the tag is irrelevant for me?

Comment: Why didn't you link the the origonal question? And what Do you mean sql is based on oracle?  SQL was initially developed at IBM by Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: @nbk - Thanks for suggestion. I have added link of my question. And sql is based on oracle means sql works on oracle database. I know sql is base query language to learn other query languages.

Comment: One of [your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898673/show-x-axis-bars-on-graph-from-high-to-low-in-chartjs-plugin) was downvoted today, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the mysql question.  Look at your profile to see that.

Comment: Losing 2 rep is nothing to get worked up over.  Normal SO usage will more than make up for that.  Well, minus this question anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant - I did not get any notification regarding get downvoted one of my posts. Otherwise I always get notification. May be one of my posts get downvoted in the past. How, I come to know whether post is downvoted in past or today?

Comment: You do not get notifications about downvotes or other events that cause you to lose reputation. If you want to look, you can go to your profile or the "achievements" icon in the top bar (looks like a trophy).

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks a lot for information. Upvoted/Downvoted activity is showing on click of Achievements icon.

Comment: @HansPassant  - Answer to post is: There is no downvote for rejecting suggested edits. Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: @Ishpreet you probably should post that comment as an answer... As it stands now there is no actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, rejecting suggested edits has no impact on your reputation or any other direct consequences at all.

You are always allowed to reject any suggested edits to your question, though if it would improve the question (as it would have in this case) there is the indirect consequence of your question not being as high quality as it could be.

Answer (score 3):

The [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) has nothing to do with oracle specifically and is for the structured query language in general. When using that tag on a question you are also suppoed to provide the DBMS implementation that is being used which in your case would be MySQL 5.7. There is nothing wrong with adding it to a question and it might help you get an answer as someone might follow that tag but not the MySQL tag and still be able to help you.

> Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.

Comment: Do you plan to actually answer the question - "Whether rejecting suggested edits voted down your reputation?"